# How to reset form elements with VueJS and Vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have a "Question and Answer" component written in VueJs, with a Vuex store.  Each answer is a `<textarea>` element, such as the following:

```
<textarea class="form-control" rows="1" data-answer="1" :value="answer(1)" @change="storeChange"></textarea>
```

As you can see the value of the control is set by calling an `answer()` method and passing the question number as a parameter.

When the answer is changed the `storeChange` method is called and the changes are cached in a temporary object (`this.changes`) per the following code:

```
props : [
    'questionnaire'
],
methods : {
    answer(number) {
        if (this.questionnaire.question_responses &&
            (number in this.questionnaire.question_responses)) {
            return this.questionnaire.question_responses[number];
        }
        return null;
    },
    storeChange(e) {
        Vue.set(this.changes, e.target.dataset.answer, e.target.value);
    },
    save() {
        // removed for clarity
    },
    reset() {
        // what to do here?
    },
}
```

If the user clicks the save button I dispatch an action to update the store.

If the user wants to reset the form to its original state, I need to clear `this.changes`, which is no problem, but I also need to 'refresh' the values from the store.  How do I do this?

Note that the source of the initial state, `questionnaire`, comes via a prop, not a computed property that maps directly to the store.  The reason for this is that there can be multiple "Question and Answer" components on one page, and I found it easier to pass the state this way.

Answer (score 0):

we can by using `refs` reset form , example

**form textarea**

```js
<form ref="textareaform">
  <textarea
    class="form-control"
    rows="1"
    data-answer="1"
    :value="answer(1)"
    @change="storeChange"
  >
  </textarea>
  <button @click="reset">reset</button>
</form>
```

***reset***

```js
reset() {
    // ref='textareaform'
    // reset() method resets the values of all elements in a form
    // document.getElementById("form").reset(); 
    this.$refs.textareaform.reset()
},
```